# Stash Embed Not Parsing

Tags: stash, parse-order, embeds

I used this technique on a site I just built with EE 2.7.0 and Stash 2.3.9. Now I'm trying the same technique on EE 2.7.2 and Stash 2.4.7, and it's not working! This is a simplified version just to show what's going on. Note: I'm using stash:get instead of stash:get_list just to dump out the data.

**index.html**

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="white_paper|c_study|video|webinar|data_sheet"
    limit="8"
}
    {stash:embed
        name="item"
        process="start"
    }
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:stash:get name="resources" process="end"}
```

**item.html**

```
{exp:stash:append_list
    name="resources"
    parse_tags="yes"
}
    {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
    {stash:item_date}{entry_date format="{gv_date_format_short}"}{/stash:item_date}
    {stash:item_url}/resources/{url_title}{/stash:item_url}
    {stash:item_type}{channel}{/stash:item_type}
{/exp:stash:append_list}
```

Instead of outputting content from the channel:entries loop, it is just outputting the unparsed tags:

```
item_title|=|{title}|&|item_date|=|{entry_date format="%M %j, %Y"}|&|item_url|=|/resources/{url_title}|&|item_type|=|{channel}
```

So it's clearly a parse order issue, and it seems like something has changed either in EE or Stash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stash 2.4.3](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Changelog#243) corrected a long-standing inconsistency with embeds set to process at the **start** of template parsing. At the other stages of parsing (`inline` and `end`) embeds are parsed by default - that is to say, `parse="yes"` is the default parameter value if not specified, and 2.4.3 added this as the default for `start` too.

To make your embed behave as it did before (to disable parsing so that the content of the embed is included in the host template without first being parsed) simply add `parse="no"` to the tag:

```
{stash:embed
    name="item"
    process="start"
    parse="no"
}
```

Comment: Ugh, so much banging my head and such a simple fix. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're using an embed for this, you're not passing anything to it so I'd use a snippet for sure.

Also may as well use set_list, open the tags above the exp:channel call

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="resources" parse_tags="yes"}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="white_paper|c_study|video|webinar|data_sheet" limit="8"}
    {snippet:get_data}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="resources" process="end"}
<div class="entry {item_type}">
  <h1>{item_title}</h1>
  <p class="date">{item_date}</p>
  ....
</div>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

**Snippet: get_data**

```
{stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
{stash:item_date}{entry_date format="{gv_date_format_short}"}{/stash:item_date}
{stash:item_url}/resources/{url_title}{/stash:item_url}
{stash:item_type}{channel}{/stash:item_type}
```

You could forego this markup and just replace your embed with a snippet instead and be done OR remove 'start' from your embed, you need it to be inline to get parse order working normally:)

Comment: I'm using a stash embed because when it's process="start", it's similar to an EE snippet, and there are a few advantages: you don't have to edit in the awful CP interface, and it's version-able. I know there are add-ons that sync snippets, but it's easier to just not deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

It's your `process="start"` parameter, I believe, that's messing you up. You're telling the Stash embed to process before the channel entries tag pair. Try removing `process="start"` and adding `parse_stage="both"`.

Stuartmcd69's suggestion is solid too.

**UPDATE:**

I respectfully bow out now that Mark has spoken. :)